# Activity indicator view

Tags: xcode, ipad

How does the activity indicator view work?

Can you just drag and drop this on a screen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you mean a [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) or the status bar activity indicator?

If you want to use a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, create one in code or IB and control it using `[activityView startAnimating]` and `[activityView stopAnimating]`. To use the status bar activity indicator, you can show and hide it like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

// do your network stuff    

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

xode 4.5.1 
add activity view controller simply drag and drop in to the view
after that click on activity view controller then control+drag to the .h file
set appropriate name
next in the .m  we can sysnthesize it and start using [activityview startAnimating] we can use hide when we need to display set activityview.hidden=True ifnot set as False